# Merge / synonymize [current-source] and [current-sink] tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed that we have [current-sink](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/current-sink) which has no tag wiki. I was going to add some information to the tag wiki but I noticed that we also have [current-source](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/current-source), which mentions current sinks and (correctly) notes that current sinks can also be called current sources. Since [current-source](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/current-source) appears to apply to both sources and sinks, and there is not really a meaningful difference between them when it comes to tagging questions, should we merge / synonymize them with [current-source](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/current-source) as the master tag?

Comment: The only problem I have with combining is while an ideal source could be labeled current -source a circuit that only sources is a current-source circuit. Should we be able to distinguish circuits that can only source or only sink?

Comment: @VoltageSpike The [main purposes of tags are for (1) connecting experts and (2) sorting questions into categories](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/32041/299342). These two tags can be merged to improve (1) -- no one is really an expert in current sources but not sinks (or vice versa), and experts in current sources/sinks can just watch one current-source tag instead of both.

Comment: As for (2) there is perhaps some benefit to keeping the tags split for that purpose (i.e. distinguish circuits that only source or only sink), but in practice and according to the current-source tag wiki we often have questions about current *sinks* which are tagged only with current-source but not current-sink (see [this search](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcurrent-source%5D+sink+-%5Bcurrent-sink%5D)). Therefore these tags wouldn't help us distinguish between circuits that only source vs. only sink unless we do a lot of retagging.